# Programmaticaly open new terminal with Bash and run commands, keeping job-control

Tags: bash, scripting, terminal, arguments, job-control

In an X session, I can follow these steps:

1. Open a terminal emulator (Xterm).

   - Bash reads `.bashrc` and becomes interactive. The command prompt
     is waiting for commands.
2. Enter `vim 'my|file*' '!another file&'`.

   - Vim starts, with `my|file*` and `!another file&` to be edited.
3. Press <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd>.

   - Vim becomes a suspended job, the Bash prompt is presented again.

I cannot figure out **a script** to carry out steps 1
and 2 without relinquishing step 3 (job-control). It would receive the files as
arguments:

```
script 'my|file*' '!another file&'
```

Can you please help me?

The script would be executed by a file-manager, the selected text files being supplied as arguments.

Do not worry, I am sane and usually do not name my files like that.
On the other hand, the script should not break if such
special chars (`*!&|$<newline>...`) happen to show up in the file names.

I used Vim just for a concrete example. Other programs which run interactively in the terminal and receive arguments would benefit from a solution.

---

**My attempts/research**

```
xterm -e vim "$@"
```

Obviously fails. That Xterm has no shell.

[Run an interactive bash subshell with initial commands
without returning to the
super shell immediately](https://serverfault.com/q/368054)
looked promising. The answers there explain how a different
file (instead of `.bashrc`) can be specified for Bash to source.
So I created this `~/.vimbashrc`:

```
. ~/.bashrc
set -m
vim
```

and now, calling

```
xterm -e bash --init-file ~/.vimbashrc
```

results in a new terminal with Bash and a suspendable Vim.
But this way I cannot see how the files Vim should open could be specified.

Comment: I had actually thought of two possible approaches, but either one had its quirks and none looked truly clean hence I just selected the one which seemed (to me) less hackish on Bash. If you wish to investigate that other one, it is by using Bash’s (and POSIX’s) option `-s` which allows passing positional arguments (the `$@` array) to an interactive shell. If no one steps in with a better answer perhaps I will expand mine to cover that one too

Comment: @LL3 I have given it a try, but it looks like the solution would be indeed more convoluted. If you wish to cover it here, it may be worth to add it as a separate answer, since it is a different solution. And so I can upvote again :). But your current answer is enough.

Comment: Thansk for the bounty! I daresay a bit undeserved according to its specific request. Anyway I have expanded the answer to cover the `-s` method

Comment: @LL3 Yeah, the bounty request was specific, but you have written a true tour-de-force on the subject, it's totally deserved! I am still assimilating the new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could think of a couple of methods, and I think the first one is less hackish on Bash mainly because it seems (to me) to have quirks that can be more easily handled. However, as that may also be a matter of taste, I'm covering both.

## Method one

*The "pre-quoting" way*

It consists in making *your script* expand its `$@` array, thus doing it on behalf of the inner interactive `bash`, and you might use the `/dev/fd/X` file-descriptor-on-filesystem facility (if available on your system) as parameter to the `--init-file` argument. Such file-descriptor might refer to a Here String where you would handle the filenames, like this:

```bsh
xterm -e bash --init-file /dev/fd/3 3<<<". ~/.bashrc; set -m; vim $@"
```

One bonus point of this file-descriptor-on-filesystem trick is that you have a self-contained solution, as it does not depend on external helper files such as your `.vimbashrc`. This is especially handy here because the contents of the `--init-file` is dynamic due to the `$@` expansion.

On the other hand it has a possible caveat wrt the file-descriptor's actual persistence from the script all the way through to the inner shell. This trick works fine as long as no intermediate process closes the file-descriptors it received from its parent. This is common behavior among many standard tools but should e.g. a `sudo` be in the middle with its default behavior of closing all received file-descriptors then this trick would not work and we would need to resort to a temporary file or to your original `.vimbashrc` file.

Anyway, using simply `$@` as above would not work in case of filenames containing spaces or newlines because at the time the inner `bash` consumes the sequence of commands those filenames are not quoted and hence the spaces in filenames are interpreted as word separators as per standard behavior.

To address that we can inject one level of quoting, and on Bash's versions 4.4 and above it is only a matter of using the `@Q` Parameter Transformation syntax onto the `$@` array, like this:

```bsh
xterm -e bash --init-file /dev/fd/3 3<<<". ~/.bashrc; set -m; vim ${@@Q}"
```

On Bash's versions below 4.4 we can obtain the same by using its `printf %q`, like this (as Here Document for better readability, but would do the same as a Here String like above):

```bsh
printf -v files ' %q' "$@"
xterm -e bash --init-file /dev/fd/3 3<<EOF
. ~/.bashrc
set -m
vim $files
EOF
```

On a side-note, depending on your setup you might consider sourcing `/etc/bash.bashrc` too, prior to the user's `.bashrc`, as that is Bash's standard behavior for interactive shells.

Note also that I left the `set -m` command for familiarity to your original script and because it's harmless, but it is actually superfluous here because `--init-file` implies an interactive `bash` which implies `-m`. It would instead be needed if, by taking your question's title literally, you'd wish a job-controlling shell yet not a fully interactive one. There are [differences in behavior](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shell-Behavior.html#Interactive-Shell-Behavior).

## Method two

*The `-s` option*

The Bash's (and POSIX) `-s` option allows you to specify arguments to an interactive shell just like you do to a non-interactive one<sup>1</sup>. Thus, by using this `-s` option, and still as a self-contained solution, it would be like:

```bsh
xterm -e bash --init-file /dev/fd/3 -s "$@" 3<<'EOF'
. ~/.bashrc
set -m  # superfluous as bash is run with `--init-file`; you would instead need it for a job-controlling yet "non-interactive" bash (ie no `--init-file` nor `-i` option)
exec <<<'exec < /dev/tty; vim "$@"'
EOF
```

Quirky things to note:

1. the Here Document's delimiter specification *must* be within single quotes or the `$@` piece inside the Here Document would be expanded by your script (without correct quoting etc.) instead of by the inner `bash` where it belongs. This is as opposed to the "pre-quoting" method where the Here Document's delimiter is deliberately non-quoted
2. the Here String (the `exec <<<...` stdin redirection piece) *must* be the single-quoted type as well<sup>2</sup>, or the `"$@"` piece inside it would be expanded by the inner `bash` at a time when its `$@` array is not yet populated
3. specifically, we need such stdin redirection (the one made via the `exec <<<` Here String) as a helper just to make the inner `bash` "defer" the execution of the commands needing a fully populated `$@` array
4. inside such helper stdin redirection (the Here String piece) we need to make the inner `bash` redirect its own stdin again, this time back to its controlling terminal (hence the `exec < /dev/tty` line) to make it recover its interactive functionality
5. we need *all* commands *meant* to be executed after the `exec < /dev/tty` (ie the `vim "$@"` here) to be specified *on the same line*<sup>3</sup> as the `exec < /dev/tty` because after such redirection the Here String will no longer be read<sup>4</sup>. In fact this specific piece looks better as a Here String, if it can be short enough like in this example

This method may be better used with an external helper file like your `.vimbashrc` (though dropping the self-contained convenience) because the contents of such file, with regard to the filename-arguments problem, can be entirely static. This way, your script invoked by the file-manager would become as simple as:

```bsh
xterm -e bash --init-file .vimbashrc -s "$@"
```

and its companion `.vimbashrc` would be like:

```bsh
. ~/.bashrc
#  (let's do away with the superfluous `set -m`)
exec <<<'exec < /dev/tty && vim "$@"'  # let's also run vim only if the redirection to the controlling tty succeeded
```

The companion file still has the quirks but, besides any "cleanliness" consideration, one possible bonus point of this latter version (non self-contained) is that its whole `xterm -e ...` command, away of the `"$@"` part, could be used directly by your file-manager in place of your "script", **if** it were so kind to allow you to specify a command which it dutifully splits on spaces to produce the canonical "argv" array along with the filenames arguments.

Note also that this whole `-s` method, in all its versions, by default updates the user's `.bash_history` with the commands specified inside the *helper* stdin redirection, which is why I've been keeping that specific piece as essential as possible. Naturally you can prevent such updating by using your preferred way, e.g. by adding `unset HISTFILE` in the `--init-file`.

--

Just as a comparison, using this method with `dash` would be far more convenient because `dash` does populate the `$@` array for the script specified by the `ENV` environment variable, and thus a self-contained solution would be as simple as:

```bsh
xterm -e env ENV=/dev/fd/3 dash -s "$@" 3<<'EOF'  # `dash` run through `env` just to be positive that `ENV` is present when dash starts
vim "$@"
EOF
```

HTH

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>with the exception that `$0` can't be specified, as opposed to when invoking a shell with `-c` option</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>if you used an additional Here Document it would need to have its delimiter quoted as well</sub>

<sup>3</sup><sub>actually on the same "complete_command" as [defined by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10), meaning that you can still span multiple lines as long as they are part of the same "complete_command", e.g. when such lines have the line-continuation backslash or are within a compound block</sub>

<sup>4</sup><sub>this should be standard behavior, presumably deriving from the first, brief, paragraph of [this sub-section](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As a simple proof of concept, I tried:

```
. ~/.bashrc
set -m
vim $arg
```

and:

```
arg=file-to-edit xterm -e bash --init-file vimbashrc
```

which seems to behave more or less as you specified, and allows you to pass arguments to your interactive command.

So, using a tempfile would probably result in something like

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "" ] ; then
        . ~/.bashrc
        set -m
        (IFS=$'\n'; vi $(cat "$tmpfile"))
else
    tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/vimstart.XXXXXX)
    for arg in "$@" ; do
        echo "$arg" >> $tmpfile
    done
    tmpfile=$tmpfile xterm -e bash --init-file ./vimstart
    rm "$tmpfile"
fi
```

Because the filename may contain `\n`, you can also use the NULL character as separator:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "" ] ; then
    . ~/.bashrc
    set -m
    (IFS=$'\00'; vi $(cat "$tmpfile"))
else
    tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/vimstart.XXXXXX)
    for arg in "$@" ; do
        echo -n "$arg" >> $tmpfile
                echo -n $'\x00' >> $tmpfile
    done
    tmpfile=$tmpfile xterm -e bash --init-file ./vimstart
    rm "$tmpfile"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, but please notice the description: There may be special characters in filenames as well as multiple file names. Your answer would only work for simple filenames.

Comment: You mean like this?

Comment: This is better, but still assumes file names do not contain newlines. As filenames may contain any character except the null byte, only null bytes would be a reliable delimiter in the temp file.

Comment: There are still some issues with this script, namely if you want to start-up `vi` without a filename. The `"$1" = ""`  should probably be replaced by a test for the existence of the `tmpfile`-variable, and it should probably have a more complicated variable name.