# terminal -e but keep terminal open if programm is closed

Tags: terminal

How can I open a terminal with a program but keep the terminal window open after the initial programm is interrupted/finished?

so it can be used like a regular terminal again

Comment: You could open the terminal with an interactive shell, then run the program from the shell. Or replace the program by a script that runs the program, then launches a shell.

Comment: What terminal are you using? Each one has its own option flags and behavior.

Comment: urxvt, but I was sort of hoping for a general solution

Comment: @berndbausch wouldn't that just close the old window and create a new one?

Comment: No, `xterm -e 'program; sh'` won't close and create a new terminal window. However, that will fail to handle suspension interrupts since there is no parent shell with job-control. [This question I have asked some time ago](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/598501) and the general answer is fairly complicated, have a look.